# Hooking LoadLibrary, how do I retrieve information about the filename that was being loaded?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm learning about hooking and decided to try hook the Win32 API function `LoadLibraryA` to see if something is injecting a DLL through `CreateRemoteThread` and `LoadLibrary`. I'm hooking from my own console application I want to protect.

I was able to detect that something inside the process space of my application is calling `LoadLibrary`, but how do I find more information about what was loaded? Could I get the DLL path and name for example?

Defining the prototype of LoadLibrary:

```
typedef HMODULE(__stdcall* LoadLibraryType) (LPCSTR fileName);
```

Instantiating a LoadLibraryType:

```
static LoadLibraryType loadlib;
```

Function to intercept the call:

```
HMODULE __stdcall LoadLibraryHook(LPCSTR fileName) {

    printf("\nLoadLibraryA has been called !!!\n");

    return loadlib(fileName);
}
```

`InitializeLoadLibraryCheck()` will be called from the main function.

```
void InitializeLoadLibraryCheck()
{

    HMODULE moduleHandle = LoadLibraryA("kernel32.dll");

    LoadLibraryType realFuncAddy = (LoadLibraryType)GetProcAddress(moduleHandle, "LoadLibraryA");

    loadlib = (LoadLibraryType)(CUtils::DetourFunc((PBYTE) realFuncAddy, (PBYTE) LoadLibraryHook, 5));

    DWORD dwOld = 0;

    BOOL bProtectRet = VirtualProtect(loadlib, 5, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &dwOld);
}
```

Edit: Forgot to add the detour function:

```
PVOID CUtils::DetourFunc(BYTE *src, const BYTE *dst, const int len)
{
    BYTE *jmp = (BYTE*)malloc(len + 5);

    DWORD dwback;
    VirtualProtect(src, len, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &dwback);

    memcpy(jmp, src, len);
    jmp += len;

    jmp[0] = 0xE9;
    //relative address from trampoline to orig function + 5
    *(DWORD*)(jmp + 1) = (DWORD)(src + len - jmp) - 5;

    src[0] = 0xE9;
    *(DWORD*)(src + 1) = (DWORD)(dst - src) - 5;

    VirtualProtect(src, len, dwback, &dwback);

    //address to trampoline
    return (jmp - len);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how do I find more information about what was loaded? Could I get the DLL path and name for example?

Simply use the `fileName` parameter that you are given.  That is the path to the DLL that is being loaded, eg:

```c
HMODULE __stdcall LoadLibraryHook(LPCSTR fileName) {

    printf("\nLoadLibraryA has been called !!!\nfileName: %s\n", fileName);

    return loadlib(fileName);
}
```

Comment: I'm getting information about my own process then. Weirdly enough. I'll show you a snapshot in 5 minutes - edit: nvm it works now! Thanks!